# summarizing 2 lists into another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 input lists like the following small example and want to summarize them:

small example:

```
a = [4, 5, 2]
b = [3, 5, 4]
```

I want to compare these 2 lists item by item and based on these
comparisons give score to every list. if they are equal both lists
would get score 0 and the item in one list is greater, that list would
get score 1. and at the end the results would be a list (named `RES`)
with 2 items. the 1st item is summation of all results for a and the
2nd item of is the summation of all results for b.
in this example, I compare item 1 of a and b and since 4 > 3, a would
get score 1. by comparing 2 other items, both lists would get 0 for
the 2nd item and b would get 1 for the 3rd item. by summation of all
scores from all comparisons, a would get 1 `(1+0+0)`and b would get 1
too `(0+0+1)`.
here is the expected output for the small example:

```
RES = [1, 1]
```

to get this results I wrote the following code in python:

```
def fun(a, b):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] > b[i]:
            AL = 1
        elif a[i] == b[i]:
            AL = BL = 0
        elif a[i] < b[i]:
            BL = 1
    RES = list(AL, BL)
    return RES
```

but it does not return what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You're rewriting `AL` and `BL` on every iteration, so the fact of the matter is that only the last iteration (when `i == len(a) - 1`) determines the result of your code. You specifically used `+` in your question, but there is not a single `+` in your code!

Comment: `RES = list(AL, BL)` is going to raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: What happens when length of both lists is not the same?

Answer (score 1):

Some issues in your code

- `RES = list(AL, BL)` is not how you define a list with two elements, you want to do `RES = [AL,BL]` instead
- You are not updating `AL` and `BL` for each iteration, instead you are resetting it to a new value
- You need to initialize `AL` and `BL` before your loop

So the update code might look like

```
a = [4, 5, 2]
b = [3, 5, 4]

def fun(a, b):
    #Initialize AL and BL
    AL = 0
    BL = 0
    #Increment AL and BL according to the conditions
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] > b[i]:
            AL += 1 
        elif a[i] < b[i]:
            BL += 1

    #Make a list and return it
    return [AL, BL]

print(fun(a,b))
```

As an additional optimization, you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over two lists in parallel

```
a = [4, 5, 2]
b = [3, 5, 4]

def fun(a, b):
    #Initialize AL and BL
    AL = 0
    BL = 0
    #Increment AL and BL according to the conditions, and iterate on them via zip
    for a,b in zip(a,b):
        if a > b:
            AL += 1
        elif a< b:
            BL += 1

    #Make a list and return it
    return [AL, BL]

print(fun(a,b))
```

The output will be same in both cases which is

```
[1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your code is:

1. AL and BL variables are not initialized.
2. You override values of AL and BL in each iteration. Try increment `AL` and `BL` by `AL += 1`
3. List class takes at maximum single parameter in the constructor. `RES = list(AL, BL)` is not valid. Try `RES = [AL, BL]`.
4. Two nitpicky details - It is not very good practice to iterate over iterable using range(len(ITERABLE)) construct. If you need index use enumerate. That way you do not need to create a new range object. So instead of `for i in range(len(ITERABLE)):` use `for i, elem in enumerate(ITERABLE):`. Also, uppercase variable names are usually used by constants.

Correct implementation is:

```
def fun(a, b):
    a_is_greater = 0
    b_is_greater = 0
    for element_a, element_b in zip(a, b):
        if element_a > element_b:
            a_is_greater += 1
        elif element_a < element_b:
            b_is_greater += 1
    return [a_is_greater, b_is_greater]
```

Edit: Shorter solution is:

```
def fun(a,b):
    return [sum(col) for col in zip(*[(al > bl, al < bl) for al, bl in zip(a, b)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variables to keep track of scores for both lists.

```
def fun(a, b):
    score_a = score_b = 0
    for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b):
        if a_i > b_i:
            score_a += 1
        ...

    return [score_a, score_b]
```

Note that I used [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) here so that we can read each element pair-wise from `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with your code.

The first is that that's not how `list` works. It takes *one* argument that is some sort of iterable, and turns it into a `list`. You want `[AL, BL]`.

The second is that you keep overwriting the values of `AL` and `BL`, so you never actually get anywhere.

I think you want this:

```
def fun(a, b):
    AL = 0
    BL = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a_value = a[i]
        b_value = b[i]
        if a_value > b_value:
            AL += 1
        elif a_value < b_value:
            BL += 1
    return [AL, BL]

print(fun([4, 5, 2], [3, 5, 4]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1]
```

That said, when what you want is the actual elements in a `list`, it is more Pythonic to iterate over the `list` directly. You can also use a `list` comprehension, for example:

```
import numpy as np

def fun(a, b):
    diff = [np.sign(a_value - b_value) for a_value, b_value in zip(a, b)]
    return [diff.count(1), diff.count(-1)]

print(fun([4, 5, 2], [3, 5, 4]))
```

This takes advantage of the fact that if you calculate `a - b`, the result will be positive if `a > b`, negative if `a < b` and 0 if they are equal. We can then take the sign of each element to count the number of positive and negative elements respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ares=[]
Bres=[]
a = [4, 5, 2]
b = [3, 5, 4]
al=len(a)
for i in range(0,al):
        if a[i]>b[i]:
            Ares.append("1")
        if a[i]<b[i]:
            Ares.append("0")
        if b[i]>a[i]:
            Bres.append("1")
        if b[i]<a[i]:
            Bres.append("0") 
        if a[i]==b[i]:
            Ares.append("0")
            Bres.append("0")
Adata= list(map(int, Ares))
Aresult=sum(list(Adata))
Bdata= list(map(int, Bres))
Bresult=sum(list(Bdata))
RES=[Aresult,Bresult]
print(RES)
```

OUTPUT:
[1, 1]

Comment: Why `append` when you can simply `+=`??? The requirement is for two sums, so the intermediate lists (which you eventually sum) are completely redundant here for an efficient solution.

Comment: Thts for string not while appending to list

Comment: instead of `Ares.append("1")`, you can simply do `Aresult += 1`. The lists `Ares` and `Bres` are redundant, and your code is an extremely inefficient solution for the given problem.